# Helm does not resolve local dependencies repository file path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

i'm triyng to do one Helm Chart for different environments. In many tutorials such scheme should works, but my structure does not read value from dependency repository. Helm just ignores it.

I have following folder structure

```
helm
   - charts
       - core-web
           - Chart.yaml
           - values.yaml
           - templates
       - frontend
           - Chart.yaml
           - values.yaml
           - templates
   - prod
       - Chart.yaml
       - values.yaml
   - dev
       - Chart.yaml
       - values.yaml
```

prod/Chart.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
name: test
version: 1.0.0

dependencies:
  - name: core-web
    version: "1.37.0"
    repository: file://../charts/core-web/
  - name: frontend
    version: "1.6.0"
    repository: "file://../charts/frontend"
```

From helm folder i execute following command

```
helm install ./prod --dry-run --generate-name -n sandbox -f prod/values.yaml
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: core-web, frontend
```

If i move charts forlder to prod folder, then everithing works.
Why helm does not accept file path from dependency repository?
It should: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to replicate the issue, seems like a cache issue

you can verify that helm dependency on which path it's looking for `charts`.

```
helm template test ./prod
#output Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: backend, web-app
```

then I tried to verify the path on which the helm looking

```
helm dep ls ./prod
```

from the output its clear it's still looking into the wrong path with the **status** `missing` as its still looking for chart inside `prod` folder.

```
NAME    VERSION REPOSITORY              STATUS
backend 1.2.3   file://charts/backend/  missing
web-app 1.2.3   file://charts/web-app/  missing
```

so to fix this

```
helm dependency update  ./prod
```

then I can see

```
helm dep ls ./prod
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a looot. It's working! 
But it generates dependencies tar.gz dependencies in charts folder. It should be there? And values from parent chart does not overriding the same values in dependent charts. Have you any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I found how to override values in dependent charts. Simply set chart name as global key.

Comment: @JDev Hi! Can you please elaborate on setting the dependent chart name as global key to override its values? I'm just starting with Helm and I'm stuck right on this one.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Vincenzo sorry, I did not understand your question.

Comment: Say `Chart1` depends on `Chart2` (via declaring Chart2 path in Chart1's Chart.dependencies). `Chart2` has a `secret.yaml` in its template folder which name is declared in `Chart2`'s `Values` file as `secret_name: someName`. If I didn't get the process wrong, by declaring the same `secret_name: someDifferentName` in `Chart1`'s `Values` file, `Chart2`'s `secret_name` gets the `someDifferentName`value.

Comment: With `Simply set chart name as global key` which Chart you're referring to? Parent or child? How you do declare it as a global key??